# react native : way to change alert to modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, modal-dialog

In my example I am interested in turning the alert into a modal I have attached below.
What is the way to do this?
I'm relatively new to js so I did not understand how to do it.
I would be happy to help with this
I tried a few ways but it did not work for me so I realized I would need some help with this

**This is the alert :**

```
function verifyBeforeSend() {
    const summary =
      'points: ' +
      nekudotDigumSelected +
      ' , check: ' +
      bundleSelected +
      ', kind: ' +
      sampleTypeSelected +
      ', words: ' +
      anchayot;
    console.log('Before send summary: ', summary);
    const boo = nekudotDigumSelected;
    Alert.alert(
      'SPEAKING NOW',
      summary,
      [
        {
          text: 'OK',
          onPress: () => {
            console.log('Test post create request');
            (async () => {
              try {
                const requestPayload = {
                  Water_Source_Code: nekudotDigumSelected,
                  Parameters_Bundle: bundleSelected,
                  Sampling_Type_Code: sampleTypeSelected,
                  Sampling_Instructions: anchayot,
                };
                const reqid = await wsCreateDigumYazum(requestPayload);
                setModalMessage('Created requet for digum yazum. Request_ID:' + reqid);
                requestPayload.Request_ID = reqid;
                saveDigumYazum(requestPayload);
                setDisplayOutlierModal(true);
              } catch (err) {
                console.log('error in wsCreateDigumYazum:', err);
              }
            })();
          },
        },
      ],
    );
  }
```

**this is the Modal :**

```
const verifyBeforeSend= ({ setModalVisible, modalVisible }) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.centeredView}>
            <Modal animationType="slide" transparent={true} visible={modalVisible}>
                <View style={styles.centeredView}>
                    <View style={styles.modalView}>
                        <Text style={styles.modalText}>
                            SPEAKING NOW..
                        </Text>

                        <View
                            style={{
                                flexDirection: 'row',
                                justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
                                alignContent: 'space-between',
                            }}
                        >
                            <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                                onPress={() => {
                                    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
                                }}
                            >
                                <View style={{ top: 20, marginHorizontal: 10 }}>
                                    <LinearGradient
                                        colors={['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']}
                                        style={{
                                            borderRadius: 40,
                                            elevation: 10,
                                            paddingHorizontal: 40,
                                            paddingVertical: 10,
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>OK</Text>
                                    </LinearGradient>
                                </View>
                            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

                            <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                                onPress={() => {
                                    setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
                                }}
                            >
                                <View style={{ top: 20, marginHorizontal: 10 }}>
                                    <LinearGradient
                                        colors={['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']}
                                        style={{
                                            borderRadius: 40,
                                            elevation: 10,
                                            paddingHorizontal: 40,
                                            paddingVertical: 10,
                                        }}
                                    >
                                        <Text style={styles.textStyle}>ביטול</Text>
                                    </LinearGradient>
                                </View>
                            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        </View>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you are trying to render a functional component.

In your renderer, you can call this function to render the Modal Component, something like this..

```
ReactDOM.render(verifyBeforeSend({true, false}), document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with React, but I've turned alerts into modals on javascript. I usually write `$('#myModal').modal('show');` at the end of the function. myModal (modal's id) is usually set to be hidden in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use `react-native-modalize` for easy modals, this saved me alot of hours and pain.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { Modalize } from 'react-native-modalize';

const modal = useRef(null);

const verifyBeforeSend = () => {
    modal.current?.open();
}


return (
    // your screen content

        <Modalize adjustToContentHeight ref={modal}>

        // your modal content

        </Modalize>

    // your screen content
)
```